# How to merge multiple data tables with specific conditionals on NA's

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have `data.table`'s that are in this format:

```
dt1 <- data.table(row_names=1:5, perf=c(2,NA,NA,3,NA), ticker=rep("aa",5))
dt2 <- data.table(row_names=1:5, perf=c(NA,1,2,5,NA), ticker=rep("aapl",5))

   row_names perf ticker
1:         1    2     aa
2:         2   NA     aa
3:         3   NA     aa
4:         4    3     aa
5:         5   NA     aa  

   row_names perf ticker
1:         1   NA   aapl
2:         2    1   aapl
3:         3    2   aapl
4:         4    5   aapl
5:         5   NA   aapl
```

I have `N` of these data tables and would like to join them so that I take the average of `perf`. However, I do not want to do this if an `NA` value exists for one of the data tables. In the case above, I would like the resulting data.table:

```
> res <- data.table(row_names=1:5,perf=c(2,1,2,4,NA),tickers=c("aa","aapl","aapl","aa,aapl",NA))
> res
   row_names perf tickers
1:         1    2      aa
2:         2    1    aapl
3:         3    2    aapl
4:         4    4 aa,aapl
5:         5   NA      NA
```

I know I could do something like this to get the means with `NA`'s removed:

`rbind(dt1,dt2)[,list("perf"=mean(perf,na.rm=T)),by=row_names]`

```
   row_names perf
1:         1    2
2:         2    1
3:         3    2
4:         4    4
5:         5  NaN
```

How would I go about setting the conditions for the `tickers` column to paste them based on the conflicting `NA`'s. Also, is rbinding all the `data tables` the most efficient way to perform the `mean` function? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
res <- rbind(dt1,dt2)[, .(perf = mean(perf, na.rm = TRUE),
                          tickers = toString(ticker[!is.na(perf)]))
                      , by = row_names]
```

gives:

> ```
> > res
>    row_names perf  tickers
> 1:         1    2       aa
> 2:         2    1     aapl
> 3:         3    2     aapl
> 4:         4    4 aa, aapl
> 5:         5  NaN
> ```

Instead of `toString` you could also use `paste` or `paste0` with the parameter `collapse = ','`.

---

Following up on the suggestion of @Frank, you could adapt the code to:

```
res <- rbind(dt1,dt2)[, .(perf = if (all(is.na(perf))) NA_real_ else mean(perf, na.rm = TRUE),
                          tickers = if (all(is.na(perf))) NA_character_ else toString(ticker[!is.na(perf)]))
                      , by = row_names]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > res
>    row_names perf  tickers
> 1:         1    2       aa
> 2:         2    1     aapl
> 3:         3    2     aapl
> 4:         4    4 aa, aapl
> 5:         5   NA       NA
> ```

Comment: is there anyway to get the NaN type to be an NA instead? and possibly also have the ticker be put as an NA as well. instead of a ""

Comment: @road_to_quantdom `if (all(is.na(x))) NA_real_ else mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)`?